# Card getting more space in the bottom

Tags: flutter

I was trying to make two cards with Expanded. Everything works fine except that the card is taking too much space in the bottom and won't stop when there is no more `TextFormField`.

This is my code and below there is a screenshot.

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    leading: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.black),
      onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
    ),
    title: Text(
      "Ajouter Un Nouveau Fournisseur",
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      style: TextStyle(
          fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
          color: Colors.black,
          fontSize: 20,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
    ),
    elevation: 10,
  ),
  backgroundColor: Color(0xFFFFFFFE),
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          flex: 6,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
            child: Card(
              color: Color(0xFFF5F5F5),
              elevation: 20,
              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 0, 10),
                    child: Text(
                      'Informations Générales',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontSize: 15,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Divider(
                    thickness: 1,
                  ),
                  Form(
                    key: formKey,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 15),
                            child: TextFormField(
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  labelText: 'Nom Du Fournisseur',
                                  //prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.perm_identity)),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 15),
                            child: TextFormField(
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  labelText: 'Siége Social',
                                  //prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.perm_identity)),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 15),
                            child: TextFormField(
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  labelText: 'Pays',
                                  //prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.location_on)),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 15),
                            child: TextFormField(
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'Ville/Région',
                                //prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
                                icon: Icon(
                                  Icons.location_city,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 15),
                            child: TextFormField(
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'Numéro de Téléphone',
                                //prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
                                icon: Icon(
                                  Icons.phone,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 6,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
            child: Card(
              color: Color(0xFFF5F5F5),
              elevation: 20,
              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              ),
              child: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.35,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                ),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 0, 10),
                      child: Text(
                        'Informations Financieres',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontSize: 15,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Divider(
                      thickness: 1,
                    ),
                    Form(
                      key: formKey,
                      autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.disabled,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 15),
                              child: TextFormField(
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: 'Nom Du Fournisseur',
                                    //prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.perm_identity)),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 15),
                              child: TextFormField(
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: 'Siége Social',
                                    //prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.perm_identity)),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 15),
                              child: TextFormField(
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: 'Pays',
                                    //prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.location_on)),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 15),
                              child: TextFormField(
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  labelText: 'Ville/Région',
                                  //prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    Icons.location_city,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 15),
                              child: TextFormField(
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  labelText: 'Numéro de Téléphone',
                                  //prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    Icons.phone,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

[image: Card Screenshots]

Comment: Can you include full widget, Seems like `flex` issue

Comment: @YeasinSheikh: full widget added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every `Column` widget, use `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,`.

```dart
child: Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  children: [
```

More about [mainaxissize property](https://docs.flutter.dev/codelabs/layout-basics#mainaxissize-property).

```dart
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.black),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
        ),
        title: Text(
          "Ajouter Un Nouveau Fournisseur",
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 20,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
        ),
        elevation: 10,
      ),
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFFFFFFE),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 6,
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
                child: Card(
                  color: Color(0xFFF5F5F5),
                  elevation: 20,
                  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 0, 10),
                        child: Text(
                          'Informations Générales',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontSize: 15,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Divider(
                        thickness: 1,
                      ),
                      Form(
                        key: formKey,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            children: [
                              Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 15),
                                child: TextFormField(
                                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      labelText: 'Nom Du Fournisseur',
                                      //prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
                                      icon: Icon(Icons.perm_identity)),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 15),
                                child: TextFormField(
                                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      labelText: 'Siége Social',
                                      //prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
                                      icon: Icon(Icons.perm_identity)),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 15),
                                child: TextFormField(
                                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      labelText: 'Pays',
                                      //prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
                                      icon: Icon(Icons.location_on)),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 15),
                                child: TextFormField(
                                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: 'Ville/Région',
                                    //prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
                                    icon: Icon(
                                      Icons.location_city,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 15),
                                child: TextFormField(
                                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: 'Numéro de Téléphone',
                                    //prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
                                    icon: Icon(
                                      Icons.phone,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 6,
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
                child: Card(
                  color: Color(0xFFF5F5F5),
                  elevation: 20,
                  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  ),
                  child: Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.35,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 0, 10),
                          child: Text(
                            'Informations Financieres',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontSize: 15,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Divider(
                          thickness: 1,
                        ),
                        Form(
                          key: formKey,
                          autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.disabled,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              children: [
                                Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 15),
                                  child: TextFormField(
                                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        labelText: 'Nom Du Fournisseur',
                                        //prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
                                        icon: Icon(Icons.perm_identity)),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 15),
                                  child: TextFormField(
                                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        labelText: 'Siége Social',
                                        //prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
                                        icon: Icon(Icons.perm_identity)),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 15),
                                  child: TextFormField(
                                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        labelText: 'Pays',
                                        //prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
                                        icon: Icon(Icons.location_on)),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 15),
                                  child: TextFormField(
                                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      labelText: 'Ville/Région',
                                      //prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
                                      icon: Icon(
                                        Icons.location_city,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 15),
                                  child: TextFormField(
                                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      labelText: 'Numéro de Téléphone',
                                      //prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
                                      icon: Icon(
                                        Icons.phone,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad to help you out, You can check more about [mainaxissize-property](https://docs.flutter.dev/codelabs/layout-basics#mainaxissize-property)